# Perpendicular tracks in 2 different layers (PCB)

Tags: pcb, emc

Many times ago I heard it's not good to have 2 perpendicular track in 2 different layers of 2 layers PCBs(I mean one track in one side become perpendicular to another track in other side of the pcb) . I can't remember what was the type of tracks (digital signals or voltage or ...)
but now in my recent pcb(it is 2 layers) because of lack of space there is a lot of these perpendicular tracks(some of them are high current- 2 to 5 amp).

- Is there any absolute rule for these kind of tracks ?
- Is it forbidden ?
- How about multilayer PCBs?

Thanks in advance

MA

Comment: are you sure you're not mixing up "parallel" with "perpendicular"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "forbidden" but there is a reason behind the advice.  It's meant to help you avoid coupling from one trace to another, and therefor limit noise or crosstalk between the traces.  This could apply to any time varying signal, be it digital or analog.  It could apply to your power traces if the flow of current is changing, or they could be the victim if a nearby signal is coupling noise onto them.

One way to avoid this is to route traces perpendicular to each other on opposite layers, and to minimize parallel run length.  The only thing that stops or reduces coupling is distance or isolation.

2 layer boards come with their own set of complications when you start thinking about current return paths.  Things get messy pretty quickly. There's no rule that you follow and you'll be OK, you have to look at your individual design and decide if the amount of coupling is too much or not.  I suppose you could simulate it but surprisingly simulating 2 layer boards is more complex than 4 :)

Multi layer boards with reference planes between them will isolate your outer signal layers from each other (as well as provide a nice clean return path).  Just another reason to consider a 4 layer board instead of a 2.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are asking, not only is it not forbidden, it is the normal way to lay out a PC board.

With a two layer board, it is common practice to have tracks running primarily vertically on one side, and primarily horizontally on the other.  This puts the tracks on the top side of the board running at right angles (perpendicular) to those on the bottom side.

Four layer boards typically have power and ground planes on the inner layers.  Boards with more layers may have internal routing layers - these would likely come in pairs, with tracks running vertically on one layer, and horizontally on the other.

Comment: it seem i understood wrong and as you and SomeHardwareGuys mentioned , i should change my sight and my design completely.